# Legendre transform for HJB PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, derivatives, convex-analysis

I am trying to understand section 2.3 of the following article: http://www.princeton.edu/~sircar/Public/ARTICLES/montreal.pdf .

I think I understand that $H_v(t,g(t,z)) =z$, because by definition of $\hat{H}$ and $g$ we have $\hat{H}(t,z)=H(t,g(t,z))- zg(t,z)$. Differentiating with respect to $g$ now gives $H_v(t,g(t,z)) =z$.

Then they say $g=H_v^{-1}$. This notation is a bit sloppy, I suppose it means $(t,g(t,z))=H_v^{-1}(z)$.

The question is how one can now recover the expressions for $H_{tv}$, $H_{vv}$, $H_{vvv}$ as given in the article. "By differentiating with respect to t,z" puzzles me.